# Where is the umask setting stored? Can this be applied to home directory other than setting it globally?

Tags: linux, operating-system, pam, umask, system-setting

umask seems to be set in various files (centos) as:

```
/etc/profile
/etc/profile.d/umask.sh
/etc/login.defs
...
```

what is the precedence order for this?

Moreover, when you set the umask using "umask xxx" where does this value gets stored?

what is the precedence order for this?

Also how do I go about setting umask for /home/ directory.
 
By default it is set to 755 which I intend to change to 750.
As I understand umask is a global setting and cannot be applied at directory. 
If this is the case what other options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the umask for /home you will need to mount this as a separate filesystem using the umask option to set the required umask. These options will need to be set in /etc/fstab to take effect when the system starts. Question really is whether you have /home on a separate /disk/partition/logical volume at the moment.